# How can I use a button to play different sounds depending the page number?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

programming newbie here. Used this guide to set up my pages:http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

And the code I use to play audio is:

```
NSString *path    = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"mp3"];
theAudio          = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
theAudio.delegate = self;
[theAudio play];
```

My goal is to play different sound files when a button is pressed, each sound corresponding to the page number. The button is constant throughout the pages, just trying to change the code that connects it to a new sound every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the current page. The delegate method `pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted:` will tell you if user has changed the page or not so you can update your current page number variable. It will look like something,

```
-(void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
{

    if(completed)
    {

        //update variable and play the audio file respectively
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not enough information was included in your code. But I'll explain a simple way to implement sound into an app that you can then build upon.

First:
Import the AudioToolbox framework into your project. Then, drag and drop the sound file into your project. Navigate to the view controller and import the header file:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

Your view controllers header should look similar to this:

```
@interface ViewController : ParentClass {
    AVAudioPlayer *_audioPlayer1;
}
```

Then, we will declare a button which we will place and hook up on the storyboard. Remember, IBOutlet is typically always weak.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
- (IBAction)playSound;
```

Now, in your play sound method, add this (Hopefully you've already realized to create a button in storyboard and link the outlet and IBAction):

```
- (IBAction)playSound
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:"nameofsound" ofType:@"wav(or other ext)"];

NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: path];

    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
    [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [_audioPlayer play];
}
```

Now, as for the page thing: UITableView has a delegate called `pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted:`. Utilize that. It would look theoretically it would like:

```
-(void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
{
```

}

At that point I load all the sounds into an array with an index corresponding to the page number,